# Drop all System.out.println in Kotlin build.gradle.kts, without permanently modifying files on build step

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I currently have a project with lots of System.out.println that I would like to strip out for Release builds.

```
tasks {
    register("removeSyso") {
       outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

       val f = fileTree("src/main/java") {
           include("**/*.java")
       }
   
       val regex = "System\\.out\\.println\\((.?|.+)\\);".toRegex()
       f.forEach { javaFile ->
           javaFile.writeText(javaFile.readText().replace(regex, ""))
       }
   }

   compileJava {
       dependsOn("removeSyso")
   }
}
```

However when I run it, it modifies my current directory files permanently. Is there a way to tell it to modify the files, but only passed the modified versions into the compile step, and leave the ones on the filesystem untouched?

Comment: You might be able to do something with a tool like _ProGuard_. Probably the better solution, however, is to use a proper logging framework and configure different log levels for development and release builds.

Comment: Like @Slaw I think you are going about this the wrong way.  The normal approach is to code all system output via a Logging Framework, then in production mode it is trivially to configure the logging system to write logging of a certain level.  E.g. see https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/kotlin-logging-library